# Best practices for DVCS and reusable Django apps

Tags: django, mercurial, dvcs

I'm getting set up with proper distribution version control (yes, overdue) on a large Django environment with lot's of reusable apps and lot's of projects.

What's the right way to do this?

1. Clone each app you need within each project, to allow you to make changes to the app without worrying about breaking anything.
2. Have one copy of each version controlled application to avoid having multiple copies of the code, each in its own repository.
3. Or is there a better way?

Thanks.

**Edit for clarity:** These are in house apps that are reused from project to project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the best practice is to keep all your apps as **one library/package**. You can have **versions/snapshots** (e.g. tags in hg) and **branches** and you should definitely create and configure `setup.py` file.

Comment: Definitely, unless your going to have each of your project requiring different versions of apps, in which case you'd probably want to distribute each application independently.

Answer (score 0):

If the app are reusables, you must create a egg in [pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi). These have releases. For each project, you could use one or the other releases.

See for example this [package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-inplaceedit).

To deploy the projects both in local as in the server, you can use [buildout](http://www.buildout.org/) (very recomended)